# How do I automatically obscure my face when using video chat?

Tags: video

I want to use Empathy, Skype, etc for video chat, but I want to have my face automatically detected and obscured in the video stream. What can I do to make that happen? I don't want to turn off video or just use a static image.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is lowering the resolution. (64x64 or even 32x32 would do it - however, I have no idea how one would go about doing that...)

Comment: Wear a green screen mask. If your camera is seeing ur face and u are just relying on software to hide you . I would think again....
Software can screw up or get hacked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A paper bag?

I won't dwell on this too long but you want to video chat *but not be seen*? Seems a little odd and a little suspicious but anyway.

I don't think anything like what you want really exists but there are separate projects that:

- Do face detection and overlays in that space ([OpenCV](http://blog.jozilla.net/2008/06/27/fun-with-python-opencv-and-face-detection/))
- A fake-webcam driver to turn a video source back into something that looks like a webcam to the system and therefore Empathy/Skype/ChatRoulette/etc ([WebcamStudio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/))

Let's be clear, you're going to have to do a little bit of work here. It's not going to be a clean solution either. But if you want it, you can do it.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's not entirely sensible, but it is fun. It's in reference to the Ghost in the Shell character that does a similar thing: http://theanimeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/screenshot_78.png

Comment: It does sound like a fun little project. The hard part is probably going to be turning what OpenCV creates into a webcam source for other things. I think WebcamStudio allows you to capture a bit of the screen and use that -- which would work well if it works.

Answer (score 11):

[Webcamstudio](http://www.ws4gl.org/) has basic face detection but you can also use it to place an image anywhere on the screen. I'll go through both. I'll be using Ubuntu 10.10 with webcamstudio_0.57alpha2_all.deb available from their [Google Code website](http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/downloads/list)

If you haven't done already follow the instructions for adding yourself to the video group as [described here](http://www.ws4gl.org/download/installing-on-ubuntu)

Once installed open up webcam studio. You should have something like this
[image]

On the left-hand side, under Devices double-click on your webcam device. Click on Apply to get turn on your webcam in the software
[image]

From here we have two options for obscuring your face. The first is to place an image over the screen. In the left-hand panel under Animations click on the waving hand
[image]

Your screen should look something like this. Click on Play to apply the waving hand
[image]

If you want to try face detection, instead of adding the hand click on the webcam device and then in the Face Detection tab tick the checkbox and choose a face to use.
[image]

To see this in action open up a program that uses the webcam. For this example I'm using Cheese. In Cheese go to Edit > Preferences and change the webcam to the WebcamStudio Video Device
[image]

Here is the waving hand in action
[image]

And here's face detection in action
[image]

As you can see it doesn't work very well. I've asked on their [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/webcamstudio/browse_thread/thread/6591efd44caafde9) for help on this matter but the response is that it's not very reliable and depends on lighting conditions and the quality of the camera.

There are other ways to obscure a video stream within that program but that's for another tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it is practical to do any kind of real-time face-hiding like this. The algorithm that you use would have to accurately detect and hide your face perfectly in *every single frame* of video. If it fails to hide your face for even a *single* frame, then you've failed, and the other person has a picture of your face.

The problem is that because of the real-time requirement, you can't review the video and fill anything that was missed by the automatic face-hiding algorithm. You have to be able to trust this algorithm to get it right on its own every single time. I don't see how you can do that.

So yeah, I vote for Oli's paper bag. It reminds me of the ([apocryphal](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/) but illustrative) story of American and Russian responses to discovering that pens don't work in space. The Americans invented a pen that *does* write in space (the pressurized ball-point pen), while the Russians switched to pencils.

Answer (score 1):

there is software to do this, lookup opencv, im 90% sure it can do what you want. not sure if its able to be implemented yet, without doing your own programming.